# py2app crashes when "requests" is used

Tags: macos, python-requests, py2app

In Python 3.11, when the program runs to this `requests` related code:

```
resp = requests.put(login_url, json=data)
```

I get this error:

[zsh: segmentation fault
/Users/luyiming/Desktop/SaQt/dist/app.app/Contents/MacOS/app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QuST.png)

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['app.py']
DATA_FILES = ['./main_w.ui', './login.ui']
OPTIONS = {
    'includes': ['requests', 'idna', 'certifi', 'charset_normalizer.md__mypyc', 'PyQt5.QtCore', 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'],
    'packages': ['requests', 'gevent', 'greenlet'],
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```